# Can someone please identify the book name from the given chapter?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Can someone please identify the "book name" where the chapter (https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/TateBT.pdf) belong to ?

This chapter talking about Tate modules, p-divisible groups, and the fundamental group. But I need to know the book name?

Please help me if someone knows the book.

Comment: This one : http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/elenalavanda/BMoonen.pdf ?

Comment: It's a work-in-progress (but apparently dormant for  a while). See [this page](https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/research.html#bookabvar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/research.html#bookabvar](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebmoonen/research.html#bookabvar)

> Webpage of Ben Moonen
> Radboud University Nijmegen
> Chair of Algebra & Head of department
>
> Jointly with Gerard van der Geer and Bas Edixhoven, I'm working on a book on Abelian Varieties. Unfortunately, the project has been dormant for a while, but I hope we shall be able to continue in the near future. Meanwhile, I here post the chapters that are currently available in preliminary form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable information. I just want to ask you that in chapter X, which I mentioned above, there is a short description to be introduced on link with $\text{formal group law}$ in the context of the chapter, I need that discussion regarding formal group law and the link with that chapter X. Can you give me information?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here is a front page of the [book](https://www.math.ru.nl/personal/bmoonen/BookAV/FrontMatter.pdf).